# How can I use XQuery to update an attribute value in an XML variable?

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, sql-server-2012, xml-dml

Trying to update one attribute in the XML contained in a variable:

```
set @x.modify('declare namespace abc="http://abcsystems.com/";
replace value of
(/abc:App/abc:Client/abc:Addresses/abc:PostalAddress)[@AddressLine1] with "555 Service Rd."')
```

Tried that with and without a subscript on `@AddressLine1[1]`.

This throws the error:

> Msg 2337, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   XQuery [modify()]: The target of 'replace' must be at most one node, found
>   'element(abc{http://abcsystems.com/}:PostalAddress,xdt:untyped) *'

There is only one `PostalAddress` element in the entire XML. What is the error telling me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the actual XML this is flying blind, but you might be looking for this:

```
set @x.modify('declare namespace abc="http://abcsystems.com/";
replace value of
(/abc:App/abc:Client/abc:Addresses/abc:PostalAddress/@AddressLine1)[1] with "555 Service Rd."')
```

The `(xpath here)[1]` is typically used to enforce one single node

### UPDATE: Working example

```
declare @x xml=
N'<abc:App xmlns:abc="http://abcsystems.com/">
  <abc:Client>
    <abc:Addresses>
      <abc:PostalAddress AddressLine1="test" />
    </abc:Addresses>
  </abc:Client>
</abc:App>';

set @x.modify('declare namespace abc="http://abcsystems.com/";
replace value of
(/abc:App/abc:Client/abc:Addresses/abc:PostalAddress/@AddressLine1)[1] 
with "555 Service Rd."');

select @x;
```

The result

```
<abc:App xmlns:abc="http://abcsystems.com/">
  <abc:Client>
    <abc:Addresses>
      <abc:PostalAddress AddressLine1="555 Service Rd." />
    </abc:Addresses>
  </abc:Client>
</abc:App>
```

Comment: @ajeh see my update... If you still have problems, please edit your question and poste a reduced example of your actual XML

Comment: Clearly, I got stuck on putting my attributes in the square brackets as in the XPath conditional queries and did not realize that an attribute name had to follow the path using nothing but the / and @ signs.